# git-credential-winstore.exe for two GitHub logins?

Tags: windows, git, github, git-credential-winstore

I use [git-credential-winstore](https://gitcredentialstore.codeplex.com/) (installed with msysgit) to store my personal GitHub account details in Window's credentials store (Control Panel -> User Accounts -> Manage your credentials -> windows credentials)  I'm now trying to use a second GitHub account.  I've modified the local git.config (`git config user.name "foo"`) but when I push, it's still trying to use the personal GitHub credentials.  I know I can change the repository url from https://github.com/user/project.git to [https://user:password@github.com/user/project.git](https://user%3apassword@github.com/user/project.git), but I'd rather not take the security risk by embedding credentials in the git.config.  I know I can go into Control Panel and flip the credentials back and forth, but that's really annoying.  Is there a way to store multiple GitHub account details in git-credential-winstore and configure each repo to use one or the other?

Comment: would love to know how to do this as well - currently using yucky ssh for my "other login"

Answer (score 2):

I have forked the git-credential-winstore to support multiple github logins.
You can find my fork here: https://gitcredentialstore.codeplex.com/SourceControl/network/forks/nickmeldrum/gitcredentialstore

(I have sent the original author a pull request but it doesn't look like he accepts them/ maintains the project anymore.)

The simplest way to use my fork would be:

1. Clone the repository locally: `git clone https://git01.codeplex.com/gitcredentialstore`
2. Build the project using the Debug configuration (should build from scratch with Visual Studio or MSBuild: `msbuild.exe .\git-credential-winstore.sln`)
3. Run the command: `InstallLocalBuild.cmd` to setup git to use this version of the credential helper

If anyone actually uses this fork and tells me about it, I will set up a proper binary download in codeplex!

### Key piece of info:

In order for this to work you need to tell git the username that you want to use to connect to that particular remote in that repo. You do that by specifying it in the remote url. For example:

`git remote set-url origin https://username@github.com/username/repository.git`

Comment: Awesome!  I'd recommend using the old URL if `username` was blank -- just in case.

Comment: Yeah that's a good idea - currently I just default the username to "unknown" in the url we store in the windows credential store. Will fix.

Comment: Great. Thanks for that. However, does not help when using gitmodules as then the URL has to be global as it is committed to the repo and I should not add my login to the URL causing trouble for others. IMHO the proper solution would be to honour the credential.username setting that I could then set in repos .git/config

Comment: Does not work: remote: Permission to m-m-m/util.git denied to xtrauser.
fatal: unable to access 'https://hohwille@github.com/m-m-m/util.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
Pushing to https://hohwille@github.com/m-m-m/util.git

Comment: So are you sure that your fix is actually in the git URL you provided?
https://git01.codeplex.com/gitcredentialstore
... I can not see your commit there in git log which should be "adds support for multiple remote users with different credentials"

Comment: Correct URL seems to be https://git01.codeplex.com/forks/nickmeldrum/gitcredentialstore

Comment: Yep. With that URL it is working as expected. Please update in your answer. Thanks.